# Combining different UIButton taps together

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm trying to make an app where the user has `4 buttons` let's say `labeled 1` through 4. If the user taps `button-1` then something happens ( I know how to do this part). But let's say I want something new to happen if the user taps button 1 and then button 2. Is there a way to combine taps if so I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: can u elaborate what you want to do..or put some code in it

Comment: you can assign the tap action for all the buttons to a single IBAction , just differentiate the tap by assigning different tag to each button.

Comment: or simply you want to perform same action with diffrent button then then you can set button tag and check it into your method

Comment: Very bad approach with ui button because you dont know how to combine the tap

Comment: keep track of an array of flags that you turn on when a button is pressed. Then you can handle whatever you want based on how this array is done. Make sure to keep some logic for the order of flags in this array though. This should be the easiest way rather then keeping track of individual flags or selection of buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can use [btn1 isSelected] method ie. you can check if btn1 is selected and then btn 2 is pressed, then perform your desired action.
What you have to do is just select and deselect your buttons when they are tapped and check for their state on other button's action.

```
  - (IBAction)btn1Action:(id)sender {
        UIButton *btn1 = (UIButton *)sender;

        if ([btn1 isSelected]) {
       [btn1 setSelected:NO];
      }
      else{
         [btn1 setSelected:NO];
         }
      }

- (IBAction)btn2Action:(id)sender {

// Button 1 outlet is myBtn1 (Suppose)
        UIButton *btn1 = (UIButton *)sender;

        if ([myBtn1 isSelected]) {
       // Pressed after button 1
      }
      else{
         // Pressed after button 2
         }
      }
```

Comment: Ok I think I understand now but how would I write it if I want to check whether button 2 is selected with button 1. I'm kind of confused how I would write that.

Comment: that means you are tapping two buttons at the same time?

Comment: Oh no that means I tap button 1 then button 2 followed right after but not at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The code Snippet shared below, gives you an understanding as to how to trigger events for multiple button click combination.
In this case, i have used only a button combination of 2.And I'm disabling the selected buttons once the event is over.

```
-(IBAction)clickButton:(UIButton *)sender
{

switch (sender.tag) {
    case 0:
    {
        if(_button2.isSelected)
        {
            //do task for combination of 2,1

            _button2.selected=NO;
            _button1.selected=NO;
        }

        if (_button3.isSelected)
        {
            //do task for combination of 3,1

            _button3.selected=NO;
            _button1.selected=NO;
        }

        if(_button4.isSelected)
        {
             //do task for combination of 4,1

            _button4.selected=NO;
            _button1.selected=NO;
        }

        else
        {
            //do task for button1 alone

            _button1.selected=NO;

        }

    }
    break;
    case 1:
    {
        if(_button1.isSelected)
        {
            //do task for combination of 1,2

            _button1.selected=NO;
            _button2.selected=NO;
        }

        if (_button3.isSelected)
        {
            //do task for combination of 3,2

            _button3.selected=NO;
            _button2.selected=NO;
        }

        if (_button4.isSelected)
        {
            //do task for combination of 4,2

            _button4.selected=NO;
            _button2.selected=NO;
        }

        else
        {
            //do task for button2 alone

            _button2.selected=NO;

        }
    }
    case 2:
    {
        if(_button1.isSelected)
        {
            //do task for combination of 1,3

            _button1.selected=NO;
            _button3.selected=NO;
        }

        if (_button2.isSelected)
        {
            //do task for combination of 2,3

            _button2.selected=NO;
            _button3.selected=NO;
        }

        if (_button4.isSelected)
        {
            //do task for combination of 4,3

            _button4.selected=NO;
            _button3.selected=NO;
        }

        else
        {
            //do task for button3 alone

            _button3.selected=NO;

        }

    }
    case 3:
    {
        if(_button1.isSelected)
        {
            //do task for combination of 1,4

            _button1.selected=NO;
            _button4.selected=NO;
        }

        if (_button2.isSelected)
        {
            //do task for combination of 2,4

            _button2.selected=NO;
            _button4.selected=NO;
        }

        if (_button3.isSelected)
        {
            //do task for combination of 3,4

            _button3.selected=NO;
            _button4.selected=NO;
        }

        else
        {
            //do task for button4 alone

            _button4.selected=NO;

        }
    }
    case 4:
    {
        _button1.selected=NO;
        _button2.selected=NO;
        _button3.selected=NO;
        _button4.selected=NO;
    }

    default:
    break;
   }

 }
```

Hope it Helps !!!